# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'solution'

Tags: attributeerror

I may have a circular dependency problem within my two python module, please help.

```
# a.py
import b
def master(worktype):
    b.slave(worktype)
    print solution

master(2)


#b.py
def slave(worktype):
    if worktype == 1:
        solution = 100
    if worktype == 2:
        solution = 200
```

I request a "worktype" number in master, then slave does the work and return the solution.
Finally, master print the solution.

Is there anything wrong that I should correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `solution` just lives in the scope of the function `slave` and can be just accessed inside this function. Use the `return` statement to return the solution of the `slave` function, i.e

```
# a.py
import b
def master(worktype):
    solution = b.slave(worktype)
    print solution

master(2)

# b.py
def slave(worktype):
if worktype == 1:
    return 100
if worktype == 2:
    return 200
```

Now running `python a.py` prints `200` on the screen.